# Dimension of the local ring as a k-vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

So I am studying the intersection numbers of two curves at a point P in $k^2$ and firstly it is described as an unique function but then for any two polynomials $f,g$ such that they don't share any component passing through P, it is defined as dim$_kO_p(A^2)/( f,g)$. My question why is it finite dimensional as a vector space.

One of the reasons is it is a zero dimensional finely generates algebra and it implies that it it will be finite dimensional vector space. How does that imply.

Comment: I don't understand the part why  $A_s$=0 for s-d>=l also in this case it is taken to be homogenous what about the general case

Answer (score 0):

Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ your local ring. As $A$ has Krull dimension 0 and is Noetherian, then it is Artinian and hence, as $A$-module, has finite length: there is a composition serie
$$ 0\subsetneq M_1\subsetneq\ldots\subsetneq M_k=A $$
where all the quotients $M_i/M_{i-1}$ are simple. The lemma below asserts that for all $i$, $M_i/M_{i-1}\simeq A/\mathfrak{m}$. Here we use a version of the Nullstellensatz: $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field, finitely generated as $k$-algebra, hence is finitely generated as $k$-vector space. As a result, by induction, all the module $M_i$ have $k$-finite dimension, especially $M_k=A$.

**Lemma**: all simple $A$-module $M$ have maximal annihilator $\text{Ann}(M)$ and $M\simeq A/\text{Ann}(M)$.

*Proof*: take $m\in M$, then the mulitplication by $m$ morphism $A\to M$ is surjective (else its image should be a submodule) and hence $M\simeq A/\text{Ann}(M)
$. Take an ideal $I\supsetneq \text{Ann}(M)$, then $I/\text{Ann}(M)$ is a submodule of $M$ and hence is equal to $M$ so $I=A$.